# Copula between a distribution and its univariate transformation

Tags: joint-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function, copula, univariate, transform

I'm trying to compute the copula (or joint distribution) between x and a univariate transformation, like say sin(x).

That is compute $C_{XY}$ (or $F_{XY}$) given that $x \sim U(0,1)$ and $y = sin(x)$

Note that I have no trouble computing $F_Y$

I think I would be right in saying that if the univariate operation is monotone, then $C_{XY} = M$ and $F_{XY}(x, y) = M(F_{X}(x), F_{Y}(y))$

And if it's counter-monotone then $C = W$

Comment: 1) What are $C$ and $W$?

2) Note that by [Sklar's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)#Sklar's_theorem) $C_{XY} = M$ is always true.

Comment: @gg  $C$ is the copula.  $M$ and $W$ are standard terms in copula theory: they are the [Frechet bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)#Fr%C3%A9chet%E2%80%93Hoeffding_copula_bounds). I'm not sure it's always the case that $C_{XY}=M:$ the possible exceptions occur for discontinuous transformations or transformations without unique inverses.

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have found an answer.

For some univariate operation $y = L(x)$ (eg. $L(x) = sin(x)$), the cdf $F_{Y}$ can be found with:

$F_{Y}(y) = \int_{L(x)<y} dF_{X}(x)$

where for a particular y, $dF_{X}$ is the probability measure in the set $L(x) < y$, so for a continuous variable it can be found by integrating the density in that region of x.

The joint distribution $F_{YX}$ is:

$F_{Y,X}(y,z) = \iint_D dF_{X}(x)$, where the integration region $D$ is where $L(x) < y$ and $x < z$

The copula can then be found using Sklar's theorem:

$C_{Y,X}(u,v) = \iint_{D_{2}}dF_{X}(x)$, where $D_2$ is now $L(x) < F^{\wedge}_{Y}(u)$ and $x < F^{\wedge}_{X}(v)$. $F^{\wedge}_{Y}$ and $F^{\wedge}_X$ are the inverse cdfs of $Y$ and $X$.

For $L(x) = sin(x)$ and $x \sim U(0,6)$, here is the copula I get:

[image]

I think that it's some combination of $M$ (where the function is monotone) and $W$ (where it's counter-monotone).

Here's what I get when I sample the copula and transform the samples through the inverse of the marginals:

[image]

I'm getting boxes because I'm modelling the descritisation error with intervals.

Thanks @whuber for the comment, I'm not sure how the above works for functions without unique inverses.